# Connect Sybase with Python in Windows 10

Tags: python, windows-10, sybase

I was trying to retrieve some data from a Sybase database using python, but I could not make it.

I tried with `sqlanydb` but it didn't work. I also tried with `Devart ODBC Driver` which is a trial version driver. But I'm looking for something which is a free/open source.

I have tried with pypyodbc and listed the driver which is in my system by running the following code.

```
>>> import pypyodbc
>>> pypyodbc.driver()
>>> ['SQL Server', 'SQL Server']
```

So right now I didn't know which driver I have to use and how to configure it in windows 10 so that I can connect to Sybase.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up an ODBC source using regular ODBC Admin, let's call the DSN ShubhamSybDB, then your connection should open as simple as this (from a .py code):

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=ShubhamSybDB;UID=<username>;PWD=<password>')
```

Comment: which driver I have to select in ODBC admin?

Comment: Default ASE 16.x driver is "SAP ASE ODBC Driver", it comes with the Sybase client install, if you opted to install ODBC support. 12.x and 15.7 drivers may be called "Adaptive Server Enterprise". There are also 3rd party drivers, but you will have to find these online and install them separately.